# Countdown Timer not working in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, promotional-banner

I tried to display the Festive offer banner in Top of the page, but it's not working. For these, I tried below code.

**countdownTimer.phtml** file

```
  <?php /** @var $block ABCSolutions\OfferBanner\Block\OfferBanner */?>

<?php $from_Date = $this->helper('ABCSolutions\OfferBanner\Helper\Data')->getFromDate(); ?>
<?php $to_Date = $this->helper('ABCSolutions\OfferBanner\Helper\Data')->getToDate(); ?>
<?php $title = $this->helper('ABCSolutions\OfferBanner\Helper\Data')->getTitle(); ?>
<?php $Days = $this->helper('ABCSolutions\OfferBanner\Helper\Data')->getDays(); ?>

<table>
    <div id="timer">
        <span id="content"><?php echo $title; ?><!--Festive Offer--></span>
        <span id="days"></span><label style="color: black;">Days</label>
        <span id="hours"></span><label style="color: black;">Hours</label>
        <span id="minutes"></span><label style="color: black;">Minutes</label>
        <span id="seconds"></span><label style="color: black;">Seconds</label>
    </div>
</table>

<?php
$f = $from_Date . " 00:00:00";
$fromDate = date("M/d/y h:i:s A", strtotime($f));
$t = $to_Date . " 23:59:59";
$toDate = date("M/d/y h:i:s A", strtotime($t));

$jScriptFunction = "<script type='application/javascript'>";
$jScriptFunction .= "require(['jquery'], function () {";
$jScriptFunction .= "jQuery(document).ready(function($) {";
$jScriptFunction .= "var timer;";
$jScriptFunction .= "var compareDate = new Date('$toDate');";
$jScriptFunction .= "compareDate.setDate(compareDate.getDate() + $Days);";
$jScriptFunction .= "timer = setInterval(function() { timeBetweenDates(compareDate);}, 1000); ";
$jScriptFunction .= "function timeBetweenDates(toDate) {";
$jScriptFunction .= "var dateEntered = toDate;";
$jScriptFunction .= "var now = new Date('$fromDate');";
$jScriptFunction .= "var difference = dateEntered.getTime() - now.getTime();";
$jScriptFunction .= "if (difference <= 0) { clearInterval(timer);} else {";
$jScriptFunction .= "var seconds = Math.floor(difference / 1000);";
$jScriptFunction .= "var minutes = Math.floor(seconds / 60);";
$jScriptFunction .= "var hours = Math.floor(minutes / 60);";
$jScriptFunction .= "var days = Math.floor(hours / 24);";
$jScriptFunction .= "hours %= 24;";
$jScriptFunction .= "minutes %= 60;";
$jScriptFunction .= "seconds %= 60;";
$jScriptFunction .= "$('#days').text(days);";
$jScriptFunction .= "$('#hours').text(hours);";
$jScriptFunction .= "$('#minutes').text(minutes);";
$jScriptFunction .= "$('#seconds').text(seconds);";
$jScriptFunction .= "}";
$jScriptFunction .= "}";
$jScriptFunction .= "});";
$jScriptFunction .= " });";
$jScriptFunction .= "</script>";

echo $jScriptFunction;
?>

<style type="text/css">
    body {
        background: #f5f5f5;
    }
    #timer {
        font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        /*font-size: 20px;*/
        color: #999;
        letter-spacing: -1px;
        text-align:center;
    }
    #timer span {
        font-size: 22px;
        color: #15b8ea;
        margin: 0 5px 0 0px;
    }
    #timer span:first-child {
        margin-left: 0;
    }

</style>
```

After printing these it looks like below image.

[image]

Well formatted in Javascript. but it's not working.

Suggest us where I went wrong?

Results are showing below image.

[image]

It's showing above image, but not countdown the time. I mean timer is not running.

Comment: please elabortate "not working"

Comment: also why are you building the JS in PHP just to echo it? seems unessecary and is not readable

Comment: @PhilippSander see my thread is updated.

Comment: 1. make sure "timeBetweenDates" is called every second as you specified it. does that work?

Comment: @PhilippSander No. I escalated, not getting any clue. Are you find any bug?

Comment: check your time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds

Comment: well.. why don't you check if "timeBetweenDates" is called every second? should be able to identify this with a simple console.log in timeBetweenDates